# ModelState on Custom membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, membership-provider

I have implemented a custom membership provider and have the following class;

```
public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
{
    #region Members
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
    public virtual string Title
    {
        get { return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Title"))); }
        set { this.SetPropertyValue("Title", value); }
    }
```

I then, in my controller want to do the following;

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult EditInvestorRegistration(FormCollection collection)
    {
        ProfileCommon profileCommon= new ProfileCommon();
        TryUpdateModel(profileCommon);
```

This kinda fails when title is not included with the error;

> Property accessor 'Title' on object 'Models.ProfileCommon' threw the following exception:'The settings property 'Title' was not found.'

If I get rid of the attribute `[Required...` it works fine but now I no longer have automatic validation on my object.

Now, I know I could check each property at a time and get around the issue but I'd dearly like to use DataAnnotations to do the work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that you are using a custom profile class as action input instead of a view model:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller you could use AutoMapper to convert between the view model and the model class which will update the profile:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult EditInvestorRegistration(ProfileViewModel profileViewModel)
{
    ProfileCommon profileCommon = AutoMapper.Map<ProfileViewModel, ProfileCommon>(profileViewModel);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think your right.  I'll move to a view model instead. Thanks